# Restricted access for different user categories in Django app

Tags: django

I am somewhat new to the django framework so excuse me if this question isn't appropriate.

I have a django app wherein I am using the built-in `User` model which django provides to store user details. I need to give access to some features of the app only to paid users. I have another `Activation` model which stores a boolean flag which indicates whether this is a free user or a paid user. This `Activation` model has user as a foreign key.

Now, I need access to this boolean flag in my template `context`. The approach which I don't think is appropriate is to add this in every context response where it would be needed. But this would be a bad design perhaps and would require significant changes in existing code. Is there a way to access this without have to send this flag in every context where it's needed, similar to the way user model is accessed to check if user is authenticated ?

Perhaps the most appropriate way would have been to create a custom user model by sub-classing the django user model and add this flag in there. But since this would require significant changes in design, I am looking for any method which would not require changing the existing models.

Comment: It would be better if you can post views.py because code will be different if it is a class based and different if it is a function based view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the views, for example if you have a view to show this information just ask  for the user activation and send the required context

```
def information_detail(request):
    # ...
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.activation_flag:
        context ={# your context data for paid users}
    else:
        context={# your context data for free users}
    # ...
```

For your other question, you can make a custom `user` model, it is recommended, because if you need to add in the future new variables to this, you'll have problems with the migration from existing users to the new model.